# Can anyone recommend an advanced .NET TabControl with native look and feel?

Tags: .net, tabcontrol

I'd like to get a .NET TabControl with a few extra features, such as:

- Close button for tabs;
- Context menus for tabs (with close this, close all, close all but this)
- Tab re-arranging;
- Tab scrolling/resizing when there are too many tabs;

I'd also like for the control to maintain the native OS look and feel. And, naturally, freeware wins over paid software. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used this one. [XtraTabControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/XtraTabControl.xml) But it is a paid software :)

Comment: Hmm... DevExpress I already have... but I missed this... I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Krypton](http://componentfactory.com) - but as I've only used the Office 2007 looks I don't know about the "native" mode...

**EDIT**
I just saw that you like  a free version better: The Krypton Navigator is not free, BUT, BUUUUTTT:

If you hurry bying it, you'll get a free license for the entire toolkit next week, because the author of the toolkit will update his licensing policy. Read his latest Blog entry for details!

Answer (score 1):

I use Infragistic's [WinTab](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wintab.aspx#Overview) control. It's really good BUT it's not free

Answer (score 1):

Use the DevExpress XtraEditors controls (XtraTab). It's free and by far the best solution you can get

Comment: Yes, I know. Someone already posted it a little while (about 2 years) ago. :)

Comment: Ooops. Maybe next time i'll read all the answers before i give one. Sorry :)

Comment: Well, kudos for everyone anyway. :)